# ng-repeat for chosen-select is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

For me static option tags are working fine for multiselect but if use ng-repeat i am not getting list of options, If i remove the "chosen-select" list is coming.
The below is working fine

```
in JS 
    var config = {
                          '.chosen-select'           : {},
                          '.chosen-select-deselect'  : { allow_single_deselect: true },
                          '.chosen-select-no-single' : { disable_search_threshold: 10 },
                          '.chosen-select-no-results': { no_results_text: 'Oops, nothing found!' },
                          '.chosen-select-rtl'       : { rtl: true },
                          '.chosen-select-width'     : { width: '95%' }
                        }
                        for (var selector in config) {
                          $(selector).chosen(config[selector]);
                        }
        }
In Html
     <select data-placeholder="Choose a Country..." class="chosen-select" multiple tabindex="4">     
                <option value="United States">United States</option>
                <option value="United States">India </option>
              </select>
```

If i replace this html code with ng-repeat it is not working.

```
 <select data-placeholder="Choose a Group" class="chosen-select" multiple tabindex="4">       
            <option ng-repeat="x in group" value="{{x.groupId}}">{{x.groupName}}</option>
          </select>
```

I am using chosen.jquery.js file also.

Comment: have you added [Angular Chosen](https://github.com/leocaseiro/angular-chosen) and tried `ng-options="g.groupId as g.groupName for g in group"` and you must use `ngModel` directive?

Comment: @Satpal i have included Angular Chosen now it's working fine but i have to hold the ctrl key for mulitiselect

Comment: <select multiple
        chosen
        ng-model="groupId"
        ng-options="item.groupName for item in group">
</select>

Comment: @Satpal tq i have used angular chosen its working for me

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/6dshj8?p=preview

Comment: Great! You can post it as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add angular-chosen.min.js and  the list(Category) is array value

```
<select  chosen multiple  tabindex="4" class="form-control"  ng-model="categoryid" ng-options="cat for cat in category" id="category" >    
    <option value=""></option>
</select>
```

Comment: <select  chosen  multiple  tabindex="4" class="form-control"  ng-model="groupId" ng-options="item as item.groupName for item in group" id="category" >    
    <option value=""></option>
</select>

Comment: But i have to press ctrl and select for multiple select